# How to use validate nested objects automatically

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Say there is a `class A` that has a reference to `class B` like this

```
class A
{
    [NotNull]
    string Alpha;
    B bObject;
}

class B
{
   [NotNull]
   string Beta;
}

A a = new A();
a.Alpha = "test"
a.bObject = new b();
a.bObject.Beta = null;
```

Now when calling something like Create for an instance of A, the code calls `NHibernate.Validator.Engine.ValidatorEngine.Validate`

But, it only validates the members of `A (Alpha)`. When `NHibernate` tries to persist the object, it fails since the database does not allows *null* for `Object`.

Is it possible to configure it so that validating `A` also validates the properties of `B`?

*EDIT:

The way I am getting around this currently is to manually call `Validate(A.bObject)` anywhere that the repository needs to create/update `A`, ex:

In the repository for `A`

```
public void Update(A entity)
{
    //I want to avoid having to do this in every class repository that has a 
    //reference to B
    var errorsList = valEngine.Validate(entity.bObject);

    if (errorsList .Length == 0)
    {
        status = base.Create(entity); 
        //Simply calls the appropriate NH function to persist the object
    }
}
```

How can I avoid repeating the line that validates `B` every time?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx), you can use Valid attribute to:

**perform validation recursively on the associated object. If the object is a Collection or an array, the elements are validated recursively. If the object is a Map, the value elements are validated recursively.**

Have you tried that yet?

```
class A
{
    [NotNull]
    string Alpha;

    [Valid]
    B bObject;
}
```